# How to separate build and version number of Flutter project for multiple flavor

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently building a Flutter project with different environments (dev, stag and prod).

With build and version number get from pubspec.yaml file.

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

How do you have different build, version number for different environments without going to iOS/Android settings?

For example: 1.0.0+10 on Stag and 1.0.0+1 on Prod.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find any solution?